# How to create a list of numbers with given range, quartiles and median?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

I have the following requirements:

> A function to create a "list" container to hold a 
>              group of data with numValues data, and the range, 
>              median, and interquartile ranges assigned. Pass TRUE if 
>              you want the data elements to be arranged in ascending 
>              order. Pass –1 for either extreme, either quartile, or the 
>              median if you do not require them to be specific values.
>              For example:
>              makelist(3, 5, -1, 8, -1, 9, TRUE) will return "5, 8, 9"
>              Both quartile values must be supplied to the makelist() 
>              function. If either one is not, they are both ignored.

I have the beginnings of the function below (In JavaScript).  I'm looking for some help in figuring out the quartile part of this (how to create the spread of numbers to satisfy the quartile requirements).

```js
makelist = function(numValues, lowerExtreme, lowerQuartile, median, upperQuartile, upperExtreme, sortData) {
  if (lowerExtreme == -1) lowerExtreme = 0;
  if (upperExtreme == -1) upperExtreme = lowerExtreme + 100;

  var magnitude = upperExtreme - lowerExtreme, // 9 - 5 = 4
    quarter = magnitude * .25,
    midway = magnitude * .5,
    threeQuarters = magnitude * .75;

  quarter = lowerExtreme + quarter;
  midway = lowerExtreme + midway;
  threeQuarters = lowerExtreme + threeQuarters;

  if (lowerQuartile == -1) upperQuartile = quarter;
  if (upperQuartile == -1) lowerQuartile = threeQuarters
  if (median == -1) median = midway;

  var step = magnitude / (numValues - 1); // 4 / 3 =

  var quartet = {
    lowerExtreme: lowerExtreme,
    lower: [],
    lowerMid: [],
    upperMid: [],
    upper: []
  }

  var fill = function(list, lowerExtreme, upperExtreme) {
    var lastPush = null,
      step = (upperExtreme - lowerExtreme) / ((numValues) * .25);
    for (var i = lowerExtreme; i <= upperExtreme; i += step) {
      list.push(Math.round(i));
      lastPush = i;
    }
    return lastPush;
  }
  quartet.lowerExtreme = fill(quartet.lower, quartet.lowerExtreme, lowerQuartile, step) || quartet.lowerExtreme;
  console.info("quartet.lower: " + quartet.lower + " quartet.lowerExtreme: " + quartet.lowerExtreme);

  quartet.lowerExtreme = fill(quartet.lowerMid, quartet.lowerExtreme, median, step) || quartet.lowerExtreme; // lowerQuartile
  console.info("quartet.lowerMid: " + quartet.lowerMid);

  quartet.lowerExtreme = fill(quartet.upperMid, quartet.lowerExtreme, upperQuartile, step) || quartet.lowerExtreme; // median
  console.info("quartet.upperMid: " + quartet.upperMid);

  quartet.lowerExtreme = fill(quartet.upper, quartet.lowerExtreme, upperExtreme, step) || quartet.lowerExtreme;
  console.info("quartet.upper: " + quartet.upper);

  var list = [];
  list = list.concat(quartet.lower);
  list = list.concat(quartet.lowerMid);
  list = list.concat(quartet.upperMid);
  list = list.concat(quartet.upper);

  if (sortData) {
    return list;
  } else {
    return list; // assume this is shuffled
  }
}
alert(makelist(3, 5, -1, 8, -1, 9, true))
```

Note: Don't have to worry about the sortData part.

These are for generating test questions. So the numbers will be used to then ask: "What is the lower quartile?", etc. So just looking to create a set of numbers with known properties of extremes, median and quartile.

Here is the function that checks the quartiles:

```
quartile: function(array, percent){ /** @param percent - pass 25 for lower quartile, 75 for upper, 50 for mean. Defaults to 50 */
             if (!percent) percent = 50;
             array = array.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
             var n = Math.round(array.length * percent / 100);
             return array[n];
         }
```

Comment: Some of your `if` declarations should be `else if` or `else` instead. If, for instance, `lowerQuartile` is equal to -1, the first `if` statement will set `upperQuartile` to -1, then the second `if` statement will see that `upperQuartile` is -1 and unnecessarily set `lowerQuartile` to -1.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly - Thanks James.  In the requirements it says if either `upper` or `lower` quartile is set to -1, then they should both be ignored.

Comment: Before knowing what operations are to be supported, why bother with extremal, median, let alone quartile values? What is going to be the signifcance of these values? What does `spread of numbers to satisfy the quartile requirements` mean?

Comment: @greybeard - These are for generating test questions.  So the numbers will be used to then ask: "What is the lower quartile?", etc.  So just looking to create a set of numbers with known properties of extremes, median and quartile.

Comment: First off, let _the_ question be easy to locate and recognise - a single sentence with a question mark, asking (for) something. The question is tagged algorithm, but I fail to recognise a description of a problem requiring a finite "sequence of well-defined steps that defines an abstract solution". Somebody might be able to advise you on a suitable data structure & algorithms - most certainly not without a description of what to accomplish. Stack Overflow may well be the appropriate StackExchange site (alternative: Code Review); OOP as a tag might be more suitable if the question is _how to_.

Comment: BTW this line looks like a typo: if (median == -1) midian = midway;

Comment: @mtyson are you looking for a full code solution or only an outline / pseudo code? Are these random numbers or a list to cover a simulation space, perhaps? Give please some background to the problem if you could. Are your quartile tests mathematical or statistical?

Comment: @Dinesh - added a bit more background to the question.  Code would be great, but anything's better'n nothing... Also added the function that checks the quartiles.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will provide enough of a skeleton that you can tweak to suit your work. As a matter of fact you already had almost all the parts.

```
// make quartiles
makelist = function(numValues, extrema,  quartiles, sortData) {
  var milestone_V = [extrema[0]];
  var milestone_N = [0];
  var q_size = numValues / (quartiles.length + 1); // because the givens do not include the extremes
  var accounted = 0;
  for ( var i = 0; i < quartiles.length; ++i ) { // easier to do with a filter!
    accounted = (i+1) * q_size; 
    if ( quartiles[i] !== -1 ) {
      milestone_V.push( quartiles[i] );
      milestone_N.push( Math.floor(accounted) );
    }
  }
  // tweak ranges for the last value
  milestone_N.push( numValues - 1 );
  milestone_V.push( extrema[1] );

  console.log("inputs:", "numValues=", numValues, "range=", extrema, "quartiles=", quartiles);
/*
  console.log("..", "milestone_V", milestone_V);
  console.log("..", "milestone_N", milestone_N);
*/
  function myfill (N, fillrange) {
    var count = Math.floor(N);
    if (count <= 0) return [];
    // fills [lower, upper)
    var res = [];
    var step = (fillrange[1] - fillrange[0]) / count;
    var v0 = fillrange[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
      var tmp = v0 + i * step;
      res.push(Math.round(tmp*1e3)/1000); // prints 3 dec digits, most of the time
    }
    //console.log("....fill range=", fillrange, "count=", count, "N=", N, "results=", res);
    return res;
  }

  // driver
  var outcome = [];
  for ( var qno = 1; qno < milestone_V.length; ++qno ) {
    var qrange = [ milestone_V[qno-1], milestone_V[qno] ];
    var howmany = milestone_N[qno] - milestone_N[qno-1];
    var tmp = myfill(howmany, qrange);
    outcome = outcome.concat(tmp);
  }
  outcome.push( extrema[1] );
  return outcome;
}

console.log( "=================")
var x = makelist(3, [5, 9], [-1, 8, -1], true);
console.log( "len=",x.length, "...", x.join(","));

console.log( "=================")
var x = makelist(22, [5, 9], [6, 8, 8.5], true);
console.log( "len=",x.length, "...", x.join(","));

console.log( "=================")
var x = makelist(21, [5, 9], [-1, 8, 8.5], true);
console.log( "len=",x.length, "...", x.join(","));
```

And the output looks like:

```
inputs: numValues= 3 range= [ 5, 9 ] quartiles= [ -1, 8, -1 ]
len= 3 ... 5,8,9
=================
inputs: numValues= 22 range= [ 5, 9 ] quartiles= [ 6, 8, 8.5 ]
len= 22 ... 5,5.2,5.4,5.6,5.8,6,6.333,6.667,7,7.333,7.667,8,8.1,8.2,8.3,8.4,8.5,8.6,8.7,8.8,8.9,9
=================
inputs: numValues= 21 range= [ 5, 9 ] quartiles= [ -1, 8, 8.5 ]
len= 21 ... 5,5.3,5.6,5.9,6.2,6.5,6.8,7.1,7.4,7.7,8,8.1,8.2,8.3,8.4,8.5,8.6,8.7,8.8,8.9,9
```

Answer (score 1):

First, we know that we need the `median`, the `upper extreme`, and the `lower extreme` in the list. There is no generally accepted definition of quartile for discrete distributions. I will assume that the following definition is used:

Use the `median` to divide the ordered data set into two halves. Do not include the `median` in either half. The `lower quartile` value is the median of the lower half of the data. The `upper quartile` value is the median of the upper half of the data.

We will put both the `upper quartile` and the `lower quartile` into the list twice. Finally, we fill the list with copies of the `median`. If any of the values are not explicitly given, we can select a valid number arbitrarily.